# Count amount using countifs

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

There are two tables.
In one table, the columns are named after the month numbers.
The rows are types of meetings: Designer, Estimator.
In the second table Column A is the date of the deal. Column B is the type of meeting.
How to calculate the number of designers in January in the first table?
I tried

```
=arrayformula(COUNTIFS('All'!B:B;"Designer";MONTH('All'!A:A);1))
```

Also I tried it withount arrayformula but still doesn't work

Comment: Use `MAP()` function and use `COUNTIFS()` inside `LAMBDA()` function. Post few sample data and show your desired output.

Comment: I have never used these functions before. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Then please share few sample data.

Comment: Should I send you link on google sheet?

Comment: Yes, you can post the link to your post or comment.

Comment: Share a copy of your spreadsheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
=arrayformula(COUNTIFS('All'!B:B;"Designer";{MONTH('All'!A:A)};1))
```

I just added brackets around your month formula.

Comment: It doesn't work( Also I tried this formula on small data amount and it was fine. But in my huge file it's not working :c

Comment: I don't understand why it is different in a huge file. Can you give me more details please?